# How to draw a 45x45 grid with SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

I am trying to make a grid of 45x45 in SDL but I am not so sure how to do it. Should I use SDL_RenderDrawLine? If so how should I use it inside my void ParticleManager::renderGrid(SDL_Renderer* renderer) function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <SDL.h>

#include "Constants.h"
#include "ParticleManager.h"

using namespace std;


Particle::Particle(double _x, double _y) :
    x(_x), y(_y),
    vx(0.f), vy(0.f),
    fx(0.f), fy(0.f),
    rho(0.f), p(0.f)
{
}

ParticleManager::ParticleManager()
{
    ax = 0;
    ay = GRAVITY;

    renderMode = "particles";
}

void ParticleManager::init(unsigned long n)
{
    cout << "Init with " << n << " particles" << endl;

    particles.clear();
    particles.reserve(n);

    while (particles.size() < n) {

        double x = rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX)*SCREEN_WIDTH;
        double y = rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX)*SCREEN_HEIGHT;

        double centerDist = sqrt(
            pow(x - SCREEN_WIDTH / 2.0, 2) +
            pow(y - SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2.0, 2));

        if (centerDist < fmin(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 0.25)
            particles.push_back(Particle(x, y));
    }
}

void ParticleManager::addBlock(double center_x, double center_y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
            double x = center_x + (j - 2) * SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.04f + (rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX)) * H;
            double y = center_y + (i - 2) * SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.04f + (rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX)) * H;

            if (x >= 0 && x < SCREEN_WIDTH && y >= 0 && y < SCREEN_HEIGHT)
                particles.push_back(Particle(x, y));
        }
    }

    cout << particles.size() << " particles" << endl;
}

void ParticleManager::addOne(double x, double y)
{
    particles.push_back(Particle(x, y));
    cout << particles.size() << " particles" << endl;
}

void ParticleManager::setGravity(int direction)
{
    switch (direction) {
    case DOWN:
        ax = 0;
        ay = +GRAVITY;
        break;
    case UP:
        ax = 0;
        ay = -GRAVITY;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        ax = +GRAVITY;
        ay = 0;
        break;
    default:
        ax = -GRAVITY;
        ay = 0;
    }
}

void ParticleManager::explode() {
    for (auto& p : particles) {
        p.vx = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX * 10000 - 5000;
        p.vy = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX * 10000 - 5000;
    }
}

void ParticleManager::integrate(double dt)
{
    for (auto& p : particles)
    {
        // forward Euler integration
        if (p.rho != 0 && p.fx == p.fx && p.fy == p.fy) {
            p.vx += dt * p.fx / p.rho;
            p.vy += dt * p.fy / p.rho;
        }

        p.x += dt * p.vx;
        p.y += dt * p.vy;

        // enforce boundary conditions
        if (p.x - PARTICLE_RADIUS < 0.0f)
        {
            p.vx *= BOUND_DAMPING;
            p.x = PARTICLE_RADIUS;
        }
        if (p.x + PARTICLE_RADIUS > SCREEN_WIDTH)
        {
            p.vx *= BOUND_DAMPING;
            p.x = SCREEN_WIDTH - PARTICLE_RADIUS;
        }
        if (p.y - PARTICLE_RADIUS < 0.0f)
        {
            p.vy *= BOUND_DAMPING;
            p.y = PARTICLE_RADIUS;
        }
        if (p.y + PARTICLE_RADIUS > SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        {
            p.vy *= BOUND_DAMPING;
            p.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - PARTICLE_RADIUS;
        }
    }
}

void ParticleManager::computeDensityPressure()
{
    // for each particles
    for (auto& pi : particles)
    {
        pi.rho = 0.f;

        // Find all the particles that contribute to the
         // pressure / density
        for (auto& pj : particles)
        {
            double distance = sqrt(
                pow(pj.x - pi.x, 2) +
                pow(pj.y - pi.y, 2));

            if (distance < H)
            {
                // this computation is symmetric
                pi.rho += MASS * POLY6 * pow(pow(H, 2) - pow(distance, 2), 3.f);
            }
        }
        pi.p = GAS_CONST * (pi.rho - REST_DENS);
    }
}

void ParticleManager::computeForces()
{
    // For each particle
    for (auto& pi : particles) {
        double pressure_x = 0.f;
        double pressure_y = 0.f;

        double viscosity_x = 0.f;
        double viscosity_y = 0.f;

        // Calculate the sum of the viscosity and pressure forces
         // applied by the other particles
        for (auto& pj : particles) {
            if (&pi == &pj)
                continue;

            double r = sqrt(
                pow(pj.x - pi.x, 2) +
                pow(pj.y - pi.y, 2));

            if (r < H) {
                // compute pressure force contribution
                double fpress = MASS * (pi.p + pj.p) / (2.0 * pj.rho) * SPIKY_GRAD * pow(H - r, 2.0);
                pressure_x += (pi.x - pj.x) / r * fpress;
                pressure_y += (pi.y - pj.y) / r * fpress;

                // compute viscosity force contribution
                viscosity_x += VISC * MASS * (pj.vx - pi.vx) / pj.rho * VISC_LAP * (H - r);
                viscosity_y += VISC * MASS * (pj.vy - pi.vy) / pj.rho * VISC_LAP * (H - r);
            }
        }

        pi.fx = pressure_x + viscosity_x + ax * pi.rho;
        pi.fy = pressure_y + viscosity_y + ay * pi.rho;
    }
}

void ParticleManager::update(unsigned long dt)
{

    // TODO: calculate the grid here

    computeDensityPressure();
    computeForces();
    integrate(dt / 10000.0f);
}

void ParticleManager::renderParticles(SDL_Renderer* renderer) {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 230, 120, 0, 100);
    SDL_Rect r;

    // Draw particles
    for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < particles.size(); i++) {
        r.x = (int)(particles[i].x - PARTICLE_RADIUS);
        r.y = (int)(particles[i].y - PARTICLE_RADIUS);
        r.w = (int)(PARTICLE_RADIUS * 2);
        r.h = (int)(PARTICLE_RADIUS * 2);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &r);
    }
}

void ParticleManager::renderGrid(SDL_Renderer* renderer) {

    // TODO: Draw the lines that form the grid
 
    cout << "Affichage de la grile (TODO)" << endl;

}

void ParticleManager::renderCells(SDL_Renderer* renderer) {

    // TODO: Draw the boxes in different colors to
     // represent the number of particles in each cell
     //
     // Use the calculation:
     // int alpha = nb_particles * 255/5;
     // if (alpha> 255) alpha = 255;
     // SDL_SetRenderDrawColor (renderer, 0, 0, 255, alpha);
     //
     // To assign the color to the cell
    cout << "Affichage des cellules (TODO)" << endl;

}

void ParticleManager::render(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    if (renderMode.find("particle") != string::npos)
        renderParticles(renderer);

    if (renderMode.find("grid") != string::npos) {
        renderCells(renderer);
        renderGrid(renderer);
    }
}
```

The end result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: What's the actual problem?  You've dumped a whole bunch of code and shown an image.  _"I am not sure how to do it"_ does not ask a question or describe specifically what you want.  It just makes a statement.  Your image shows a grid filled with a bunch of filled rectangles of varying colors.  Are you asking about how to draw the grid only?  Or the rectangles only?  Or both?  Or are you asking how to use loops?  To answer _"should I use `SDL_RenderDrawLine`?"_ we would need to know these things.  My question to you is: Have you actually tried it?  What happened?  Why are you asking?

Comment: What's the issue then?  Your code shows no trace of you having tried it, and you have not shown an image to show the result, which I can only presume did not display the way you expected.  Drawing a grid is very simple.  You just loop over each row and draw the horizontal lines from the left edge to the right edge.  Then you loop over each column and draw the vertical lines from the top edge to the bottom edge.  Two separate loops.  Easy.  So again, what did you try and what happened?